# Xcode cannot resolve zlib symbols

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker, symbols

I use the zlib library to do data compression in a command line tool for Mac.

On Xcode 4, I get an error "undefined symbol" on zlib functions.

I search for the libz.dylib on mac computer and I find 3 files in `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform`.

Nothing in `/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform`.

Why? Where I can find my libz.dylib library for architeture i386?

Comment: Xcode can't find the symbols, or the `ld` can't?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Xcode 4 have a look at your Build Phases.

Go to the 3rd section - Link Binary with libraries

Click the `+` button

choose libz.dylib in the drop down.
[image]

Comment: Great Abizern !
Thanks a lot !

Comment: I have the same problem. I added the framework properly, but that did not work! Can it be something else? Does the zlib for ios differ from GNU zlib? My linker cannot find res_9_... things.

Comment: Update all the way from 2015: It solved an issue with zlib.h from a C++ project.

Answer (score 0):

You can download zlib from its [site](http://zlib.net/), look further down in the page for the download links.

You can also happen to have installed [macports](http://www.macports.org/) or [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/). In this case, you get there prebuilt versions.